Installing vent for second floor
I have a wood stove on my first (ground) floor that does a poor job heating the master bedroom directly above it. Air needs to go down a long hallway, up a flight of stairs, and down another long hallway to get from the stove to the bedroom. I would like to add a vent, or register, in the bedroom floor to improve airflow.
I've found both floor and ceiling registers, but I would think that I need a product that is a connected ceiling to floor register.

Does such a product exist?
If not, do I just use one floor and one ceiling register?
Would I put anything between them in the empty floor space?

Regarding fire code, I believe that this is permitted as long as the registers have dampers.

the technology exists ... look at how forced air central heating works

A simple duct between the ceiling and floor to connect the two vents/registers

No, such a product does not exist. You need to build one to suit your needs. Simple plywood panels and the two louvers will do.
